# Doctrine cascade delete query?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I am using following query to delete countries in my database but it is giving foreign key error because countries has one to many relationship with cities.

I am using following query :

```
$cd = 1;
Doctrine_Core::getTable('country')->find($cd)->delete();
```

this query soft deletes if countries doesn't have any child but gives error if countries have any city.

I have also done following settings in country model:

```
$this->hasMany('city', array(
'local' => 'id',
'foreign' => 'country_id',
'cascade' => 'delete'
));
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think above way is also correct but I solved it in following way.

I made relation of country to city like this :

```
$this->hasMany('city', array(
     'local' => 'id',
     'foreign' => 'country_id',
    'cascade' => array(
     0 => 'delete',
     )));
```

In YAML file I added like this  :
cascade: [delete]

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In BaseCity.php you should have a relation to Country. In:

```
$this->hasOne('Country', array(
...
```

add this line:

```
"onDelete"=>"CASCADE"
```

When you delete country, cities will be deleted too. If you want to keep them, put

```
"onDelete"=>"SET NULL"
```

Comment: @Zelijko : I am using "onDelete"=>"SET NULL" as suggested by you. My both models has SOFTDELETE behaviour. It's setting parent deletion = 1 but not setting then children row = 1 (attached to the parent)